# How to can I get the opposite values to between?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am trying to get the opposite values to between

I get a few data of this way:

```
x[x.between(x.quantile(0.25), x.quantile(0.75))]
```

But I need the opposite data, how can get it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `~` to negate. 
`x[~x.between(x.quantile(0.25), x.quantile(0.75))]`